# Is there a word in English which expresses the idea of 'logicate' (which is not an English word)?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, logic, intuition, thought

I am trying to translate the Greek word λογιξομαι, *logitsomai*,which is usually translated 'account' or 'reckon' which I do not think quite catch the meaning.

In English, we have words for numerical logic, for example 'calculate' and 'enumerate'; and we also have words for thought processes like 'reason', 'reckon' or 'estimate', some of which are financially appropriate, such as 'account'. 'Reckon' to me, is one of these - 'reckoning the books' used to mean reckoning up the double entry account ledgers at the end of a financial period.

But I cannot find a word which carries the idea of pure, intuitive logic.

'Reason' has connotations of disingenuity, a matter of a reason behind the reason. It is not intuitive logic. It reasons, often with an underlying motive.

But λογιξομαι, *logitsomai*, represents, to me, a logical view that is not cognitive, but intuitive. It views something conceptual, and immediately 'sees' what is right about it, logically.

The best I can come up with, after a long time considering it, is 'logicate' which is available in English it seems to me; but it is not an English word.

[Edit after post : I am translating a biblical word but this is a matter of translation into colloquial English, not theology. One of the main places 
is "Abraham believed God - and there was XXXXX to him, unto righteousness".
From the very open structure of the wording (it is intransitive and so-called "deponent") it is clear that something is seen, logically, and it is attributed (a close word to λογιξομαι, *logitsomai*) to Abraham.

Comment: Well, there's _intuit_ and perhaps _apprehend_, and even _see_ ... but none of these specifically relate to logic. Depending on context, _derive_ or _infer_ might work. Perhaps you could give your translation of the whole sentence/paragraph with a placeholder for the word you're looking for.

Comment: Would deduce work?

Comment: *Logic* is defined as the opposite of *intuitive*; I think the question needs more explanation.

Comment: Perhaps "and there was _considered_ to him, unto righteousness"?

Comment: @TimLymington It appears to me to be not a matter of processed thought. One does not have to think about something if one immediately sees it as 'right' or 'righteous'. It is there - and it is right.

Comment: From the context, perhaps "obvious" or "obviousness"?

Comment: While I quite like my suggestion _considered_, my feeling is that it would be good to find a word with more in common with _attributed_ and/or _predicated_. I guess you could use those words. Theasurus.com also led me to _ascribed_ and _imputed_, I'm not sure, and not being familiar with the Greek concepts, I don't know if any of these is better, but thought it was worth throwing them out there.

Comment: This is unclear. Can you clearly give a couple examples of Bible translations (with stated chapter/verse)? That way we can see what others have tried and how we might make other choices according to your understanding.

Comment: You're working from a Greek word  but the verse ultimately goes back to the Hebrew in Genesis 15:6. Greek words can only approximate Hebrew ones, and English ones only approximate Greek ones.

Comment: In the US, the Declaration of Independence uses the notion of "self-evident truths". In this sense, the word is more like *innate* or *inherent*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Deduce/deduction

> But λογιξομαι, logitsomai, represents, to me, a logical view that is not cognitive, but intuitive. It views something conceptual, and immediately 'sees' what is right about it, logically.

My first idea would be **to deduce** (noun: deduction).

> [**Deduce**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deduce)
>   *verb*
>
> Arrive at (a fact or a conclusion) by reasoning; draw as a logical conclusion.
>   *‘little can be safely deduced from these figures’*

---

### **Edit**

I only read your comment after I had answered.

> Again, I would say that deduce is cognitive process, not intuition.

I agree with your comment by itself (logic is a cognitive process), but then your question is wrongly conflating "logic" and "intuition" to mean the same thing, which is not the case. **Logic is not intuitive**. If you logically come to a conclusion, that means you have used cognitive processes.

This is further confirmed by the dictionary definition of [logic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/logic):

> **Reasoning** conducted or assessed according to strict principles of validity.

This clashes with the dictionary definition of [intuition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intuition):

> The ability to understand something instinctively, **without the need for conscious reasoning.**

**One possible exception** - In an informal setting, "logical" is often used as a synonym for "obvious", which can make it seem like an equivalent to "intuitive". But it is important to observe that this informal meaning is not listed in the dictionary:

> [**Logical**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/logical)
>   *adjective*
>
> 1. Of or according to the rules of logic or formal argument.
>      *‘a logical impossibility’*
>
> 1.1. Characterized by or capable of clear, sound reasoning.
>   *‘her logical mind’*
>
> 1.2. Expected or sensible under the circumstances.
>   *‘the polar expedition is a logical extension of his Arctic travels’*

You cannot use "intuitive" in any of the example sentences without changing its meaning. "intuitive" and "logical" are not interchangeable, as they do not mean the same thing.

---

### Reason is correct too.

> But I cannot find a word which carries the idea of pure, intuitive logic. 'Reason' has connotations of disingenuity, a matter of a reason behind the reason. It is not intuitive logic. It reasons, often with an underlying motive.

You're conflating two different meanings of the word "reason". These two meanings are completely separate from each other.

[Reference link here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reason)

**1. As a noun, it can refer to "a justification"**

> **Reason**
>   *noun*
>
> A cause, explanation, or justification for an action or event.
>   *‘she asked him to return, but didn't give a reason’*
>   *‘I resigned for personal reasons’*

In other words, this meaning relates to the bolded word in your statement:

> a matter of a **reason** behind the reason

**2. Both as a (mass) noun and a verb, it can refer to "rational thought, deduction"**

> **Reason**
>   *mass noun*
>
> The power of the mind to think, understand, and form judgements logically.
>   *‘there is a close connection between reason and emotion’*
>
> **Reason**
>   *verb*
>
> Think, understand, and form judgements logically.
>   *‘humans do not reason entirely from facts’*

In other words, this meaning relates to the bolded word in your statement:

> a matter of a reason behind the **reason**

These two meanings of "reason" are not connected. You can use one without necessarily implying the other.

However, if you want to disambiguate (because the context does not already make it clear which meaning you're referring to), then you can use **reasoning**.

Since the verb "to reason" exclusively refers to "rational thought" and not "a justification", and "reasoning" is derived from the verb, that means there is no ambiguity here.

Answer (score 2):

Abraham believed God - and there was ***certainty*** to him, unto righteousness.

***Edit:***

Truth; resides in the ***certainty*** to comprehend that two plus two make four. If that is granted, all else follows... ***1984***

*Original Quote:*

*"Freedom is the freedom to say that two plus two make four. If that is granted, all else follows"*.

***Edit:*** [Additional thoughts, retort (maybe)]

I would just like to add the following context. Thanks.

Consider the **regal** tones of reason in the **light** of certainty:

> *Reason is the power to **judge** as certainty is the freedom to **believe**.*
>
> *Reason is to find **deceit** as certainty is to know **truth**.*
>
> *Reason is to harbour **doubt** as certainty is to embrace **conviction**.*
>
> *Through **reason** you may find **certainty**.*
>
> *But faith in **God** cannot be reasoned!*

Comment: I like this, but can you support it, preferably with cited sources?

Comment: @TaffeyL This is intriguing. Can you reference, please ?

Comment: @Nigel J Forgive me; I have no source to reference. I can provide a metaphor / analogy to help. Good luck in your search.

Comment: @NigelJ I have updated my answer . Thanks. Hope you like it. Have a good day.

Comment: @TaffeyL I think your edit might be judged off-topic here, but I will leave that to others. The word 'evaluate' has come forward in my mind as a candidate, but this was voted down so I deleted the post.

Answer (score 1):

This does not fit the translation phrase you presented, but in terms of an "intuitive truth", you can use the word ***postulate***:

> **2a** :to assume or claim as true, existent, or necessary :depend upon or start from the postulate of
>     **b** :to assume as a postulate or axiom (as in logic or mathematics)
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/postulate)</sub>

I was thinking about the notion of *first principles* when giving this answer. The idea is that there is a such a thing as a true statement that people are willing to accept as fact without proof.

> A **first principle** is a basic, foundational, self-evident proposition or assumption that cannot be deduced from any other proposition or assumption. In philosophy, first principles are taught by Aristotelians and a nuanced version of first principles are referred to as *postulates* by Kantians.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_principle)</sub>

However, another word to consider for your sample sentence is ***sincerity***.

> The quality of being free from pretense, deceit, or hypocrisy.
>   *'the **sincerity** of his beliefs is unquestionable'*
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sincerity)</sub>

The word has as a close synonym *truthfulness*, which is close your notion of an inherent logical truth. So, in your sentence:

> Abraham believed God - and there was *sincerity* to him, unto righteousness

Answer (score 1):

You need to get away from the idea of "logic". Though **logos** is a valuable and important word, the English descendant *logic* has nothing to do with emotion or intuition (just ask Mr Spock). It's a near-synonym of *reason*, and your use of the term in the question is (with due respect) misleading.

I think you may need to get away from literal translation and find something in English with a similar connotation. A semi-financial term like "It was credited to him as righteousness" might do, but I think *prove* is best. I appreciate that it is non-exact, but in your example Abraham's belief was precisely proof of his righteousness, and the etymology, of passing a test, is also helpful.